# Editar el mensaje al no cumplir los requisitos de una contraseña

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A la contraseña le dí el atributo de

```
pattern='^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$'
```

lo que este atributo hace es pedir que la contraseña tenga como minimo 8 caracteres, una minuscula, una mayuscula y un numero.

Si es que yo le doy al submit sin haber completado los requisitos me salta un mensaje diciendo "Utiliza un formato que coincida con el solicitado" que supongo que es un mensaje por defecto del navegador.

TL;DR: me gustaria personalizar el mensaje por defecto del navegador cuando no cumplo los requisitos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu cuentas con un `id` puedes asignárselo a una variable en Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('username');
```

Después podrás validar si el input realizó la acción de manera inválida, usarás `event.target.setCustomValidity` con el nuevo mensaje que se desea:

```
input.oninvalid = function(event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Este es mi mensaje de ejemplo.');
}
```

Prueba con eso, espero te ayude.

Comment: Gracias, sabrías si podría personalizar el mensaje dependiendo de que falte en la contraseña, si no introdujo numeros "Mensaje 1", si no introdujo letras mayusculas "Mensaje 2", entre otros

Comment: La verdad nunca he validado de tal modo, normalmente cuando lo utilizo generalizo la respuesta de error, algo como "Su contraseña debe contar con al menos una mayúscula y un número.". Supongo que es posible si validas el contenido de la contraseña y según sea el caso cambias el valor del event.target.setCustomValidity(). Fue un placer ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Con `jQuery` accedes a la propiedad de si es válido o no de acuerdo al patrón marcado en el input y cambiar el mensaje con `setCustomValidity`.

```
$("input[name=contrasena]").on("invalid", function() {
   this.setCustomValidity("Este es mi mensaje personalizado");
});
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando [aquí](http://jsfiddle.net/yT3w3/). Sacado de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19123002/5675636).